# adding a develpment device to a push notification certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I have 2 development devices. I have push set up and both devices get the notifications my server sends.

I added a third device. I registered it in the dev center and deployed the app to it. Also, when I look in the provisioning profiles, I can clearly see all three devices there.

App works but the 3rd device does not get the notifications managed via APN cert I hold in Parse which I generated before I added the 3rd device.

So the first action I took was to create a new APN cert and upload it to Parse. Unfortunately, the 3rd device still does not get the push notification.

Do I need to delete all profiles, certs, app ids and start from scratch? I'm at a loss.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

make Sure you edited the development provisioning profile to add the new devices and all are marked not only exists.

Comment: I did. This is a profile managed by xcode itself. When I look at it in the Apple Dev Center it clearly states 3 devices (although I am not sure where in xcode I can see which devices...but I can see them in the apple dev center)

Comment: did you refresh your xcode provisioning profiles from your Xcode settings ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. It came down to code signing in xcode.

The checks I took to figure it out:

1. Check Parse push report - found one invalid token
2. Device was registered correctly (UUID) in the Apple Dev Center
3. Device token (captured in a print statement in xcode) matched record in Parse
4. An updated (generated after new device added) APN cert was added to Parse
5. Previous devices got all Push notifications

Having eliminated all of the above, I looked at xcode **project -> Target -> Code signing** to check that the app was deployed with the correct Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile. To my surprise, it was assigned my personal dev identity as oppose to iOS developer + team provisioning profile.

Once fixed and redeployed, all push notifications started flowing through.

What I am not clear about is why/how this parameter changed. I have not changed it. The **only** thing I've done in the last week or two was to upgrade to the latest xcode and Swift 2. But I guess I did do something somewhere otherwise it would not have happened.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same exact issue and here is how I solved the problem.

I open the existing provisioning profile from my Apple Developer center (the profile for my app of course). Edited and added the new device from there. Re-generated and downloaded the new profile.

Then I open my Xcode, from the menu: 
1. XCode/Preference, choose Accounts Tab. 
2. Located the Apple ID for my App from the left hand panel. Then click on "View Details". 
3. Click on "Download All".
4. Then re-ploy my mobile app to the new device. (via connect the new device to your Mac, run from xcode).

I hope this help.